# Get quarter on quarter growth with SQL for current quarter

Tags: sql, date, join, group-by

I'm trying to get the quarter on quarter revenue growth for only the current quarter from a dataset. I currently have a query that looks something like this

```sql
Select
  x.Year,
  x.quarter,
  x.product,
  x.company_id,
  y.company,
  SUM(x.revenue)
FROM 
  company_directory y
  LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
  DATEPART(YEAR, @date) year,
  DATEPART(QUARTER, @date) quarter,
  product,
  SUM(revenue)
FROM sales
WHERE year => 2018 ) x
ON y.company_id = x.company_id
```

The data I get is in this format

```sql
Year  Quarter  Product  company_id  company    revenue
2020  Q2       Banana   1092        companyX   $100
```

What I'm trying to do is get quarter on quarter growth for revenue if it's reporting the current quarter. So for example, in the above data, because we're in Q2-2020, I want an extra column to say QoQ is x% which will compare Q2 vs Q1 revenue. If the row is reporting Q1-2020 or Q2-2019 QoQ will be empty because neither of those are the current quarter based on today's date.

Expected result

```sql
Year  Quarter  Product  company_id  company    revenue  QoQ
2020  Q2       Banana   1092        companyX   $100     20%
2020  Q1       Pear     1002        companyX   $23      NULL
```

I'm not entirely sure how to go about this, haven't had much luck searching. Any idea how I can implement?

Comment: `DATEPART` is not MySQL. Please tag your question with the correct DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.

```
select
    s.yr,
    s.qt,
    s.product,
    s.company_id,
    cd.company,
    s.revenue,
    1.0 * (
        s.revenue 
        - lag(s.revenue) over(partition by s.product, s.company_id order by s.yr, s.qt)
    ) / lag(s.revenue) over(partition by s.product, s.company_id order by s.yr, s.qt) as QoQ
from company_directory cd
inner join (
    select
        datepart(year, sales_date) yr,
        datepart(quarter, sales_date) qt,
        product,
        company_id,
        sum(revenue) revenue
    from sales
    where sales_date >= '2018-01-01'
    group by 
        datepart(year, sales_date) year,
        datepart(quarter, sales_date) quarter,
        product,
        company_id
)  s on s.company_id = cd.company_id
```

Notes:

- your code is not valid MySQL; I assume that you are running SQL Server instead of MySQL
- the use of a variable in the subquery does not make sense - I assume that you have a column called `sales_date` in table `sales` that holds the sales date
- your `group by` clauses are inconsistent with your `select` clauses - I assume that you want the quarter to quarter sales growth per company and per product
- you might need to ajust the `QoQ` computation to *your* actual definition of the quarter to quarter growth
- I don't see the point for a `left join`, so I used `inner join` instead

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying these in the original post. But your suggestion did work for my use case. Thanks a lot, also reading up on the lag function now.

Answer (score 0):

You need analytical window function LAG

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=40a7ba897df766f913ebd99e2f2a0f4e